# Cannot access a disposed context instance - on the first run

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

This is a common exception when one tries to access a disposed context. However, I get this exception the first time I access the context and can't figure out why it would happen.

This is the code I use to register my context as a `Transient`

```
public static IServiceCollection AddSQLContext<TContext>(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString, ServiceLifetime serviceLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Transient)
            where TContext : DbContext => services
            .AddDbContext<TContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
               connectionString,
               actions => actions.MigrationsAssembly("Discounted.Data")
                                 .EnableRetryOnFailure()
               ), serviceLifetime);
```

This is the code in `Blazor Server` front end that calls the service throwing the exception:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        using (var source = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            version = VersionService.Version;
            ProtectedBrowserStorageResult<string> customer = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<string>("customer");
            DashboardDto.LocalUser = customer.Value;

            if (DashboardDto.LocalUser == null) return;

            // Get the subscription status
            // ===> Does not access the context
            DashboardDto.LocalStatus = await SubscriptionService.GetSubscriptionStatusAsync(DashboardDto.LocalUser, source.Token);

            // Load the image
            // ===> Accesses the context for the first time
            // ===> Throws Exception from GetQRCodeAsync
            DashboardDto.StoreId = await QRCodeService.GetQRCodeAsync(DashboardDto.LocalUser, source.Token);

            // Get the rewards
            DashboardDto.Rewards = await RewardService.GetRewardAsync(DashboardDto.StoreId, source.Token);
        }

        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

This is the `GetQRCodeAsync` function and the `RewardService`:

```
public class QRCodeService : IQRCodeService
{
    private IAccountRepository _accountRepository;

    public QRCodeService(IAccountRepository accountRepository)
    {
        _accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }

    public async Task<string?> GetQRCodeAsync(string customerId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Throws Exception here
        Account store = await _accountRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.StripeId == customerId, cancellationToken);

        return store.StoreCode.ToString();
    }
}
```

I am registering all my services and repositories as `Transient` as well. I am unsure what is causing the issue since this is the first call to the back end that I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

Use the method `OnAfterRenderAsync` instead of `OnAfterRender`.

You are getting an error because you are doing async operation in void function. This means that the main thread will not wait for the function `OnAfterRender` and is considering the request completed, therefore disposing the dbcontext.

Comment: Now that I tested it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting the same error? Can you explain how it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes I am getting the same error

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `OnAfterRenderAsync`  and not `OnInitializedAsync`? If not, try using it.
According to the docs, `OnAfterRenderAsync` is useful for "performing interop, or interacting with values received from @ref".  Which are not the things you are doing in the code.

Comment: I use js calls within that function which prevents me using OnInitializeA